# How to create a splashscreen for android using Sencha touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, splash-screen

I want to create a splash screen for sencha touch 2. my requirement is first i will show a view with 3 secs and then i have to move to another view. How can i do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u r using phone gap framework then u can create a splash screen by writing two lines

```
     super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 5000);
```

and

```
      super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
```

in ur java file.

and if u r not using phone gap framework follow [this](http://davehiren.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-create-splash-screen-for-sencha.html)